# Adding backup payment method from second account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can not add backup payment method from another account which has `owner` privileges.

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puohc.png)

I went to `Billing->Payment Setting->Payment Users`, but could not add another payment user. I saw only organization account can have multiple payment users.

I have a card for payment method which is not working and someone else needs to add another card for primary/backup payment method. How can I solve this problem? Another account with owner permission is not able to add backup payment method.

Comment: The error message explains what to do. Contact the person with billing admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add more users with Principal permissions in the billing account. Then those uses should be able to add their card and make the payment.

Alternatively, try to add the new card once from your(owner) account. Once the card is added, the other person can make the payments from his account.

Comment: I'm not able to add more users because my account was personal, I found out that only organization can add more than one payment users. Do you have any idea how can i remove previous and add new payment user?